# Drag and Drop Shape Target VBA in Excel - Shape Object is Locked and not Draggable

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to work with 2 shapes to start with. Shape1 is the object to be dragged and Shape2 is the target. I think that I have all the properties set correctly for dragging, but Shape 1 seems to be locked and not draggable. The cursor changes to the pointer icon when I hover over Shape1, but when I click and drag it does nothing. Any help is appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim shp As shape
    
    For Each shp In Sheet1.Shapes
        shp.FillFormat.Locked = False
    Next shp
    
    ' Unlock draggable shapes
    Me.Shapes("Shape1").Locked = False
    Me.Shapes("Shape2").Locked = False
    
    ' Set Shape1 as the target for Shape2
    Me.Shapes("Shape2").OnDragOver = "DragShape"
    
    ' Assign event handlers to draggable shapes
    With Me.Shapes("Shape1")
        .OnAction = "DragShape"
        .OnDoubleClick = "ResetShape"
        ' Enable dragging for Shape1
        .DragBehavior.Enabled = True
    End With
    
    With Me.Shapes("Shape2")
        .OnAction = "DragShape"
        .OnDoubleClick = "ResetShape"
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub DragShape()
    ' Enable shape dragging
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Me.Shapes(Application.Caller).DragBehavior.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub ResetShape()
    ' Reset shape position
    Me.Shapes(Application.Caller).Top = 100
    Me.Shapes(Application.Caller).Left = 100
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim dropTarget As Range
    Set dropTarget = Me.Range("A1")
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, dropTarget) Is Nothing Then
        Dim shp As shape
        Dim draggableShape As shape
        
        Set shp = Me.Shapes(Target.Value)
        Set draggableShape = Me.Shapes(Target.Offset(0, 1).Value)
        
        If shp.Left = draggableShape.Left And shp.Top = draggableShape.Top Then
            ' Matched! Snap draggable shape to target shape
            draggableShape.Top = shp.Top
            draggableShape.Left = shp.Left
            draggableShape.FillFormat.Locked = True
        Else
            ' Not matched! Snap draggable shape back to its original position
            draggableShape.Top = 100
            draggableShape.Left = 100
        End If
        
        ' Clear cell contents after matching or snapping back
        Target.ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```

I reviewed all the code and it seems right to me. Obviously, something is missing. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where are you getting that `DragBehavior` property from for the Shape?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape#properties

Comment: I now realize that it is for text boxes and not shapes. maybe I could achieve the same functionality from text boxes, but I am not sure that is what we want.  Do you have any pointers for how I might achieve a drag-and-drop with shapes where one shape is the target of the other?  I  know there is JS for this stuff and there are already applications that do it, but we have some specific things we teach in Excel and want to use Excel as the base.  The MS reference is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dragbehavior-property

Comment: The doc you link to has "starts a drag-and-drop operation on the selected **text**"  That's about dragging text, not the textbox itself.  There's not much in VBA/Excel which supports what you're describing (dragging one shape onto another).